# Automated search of misplaced points with Python or Model Builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2.

My work is to find points which are misplaced.

I want to know if there's a way to automate this using Python or Model Builder?

I wish to place this in the attribute table which will output a '1' if there's a misplacement of a point in a field.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What determines if a point is "misplaced"?

Comment: a field of classification called "Zones"

Comment: example 

ZO1 
ZO2 

ZO1 all have to be in the same area

Comment: ZO1 all have to be in the same area

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include these details - probably as a graphic of some rows from the attribute table that have values you want given a 1 in the "misplaced field".

Answer (score 3):

I would [spatial join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000q000000) the area layer to the point layer. That should create a new point file with the area information joined to each point. I would go into the new attribute table, create a new 'Misplaced' Field and then [field calculate](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Calculate_Field_examples/005s0000002m000000/) "1" if "Points.Zones" <> "Area.Zones"

Perhaps you can run a nearest neighbor analysis on the point file. That would tell you the closest point to each point. If the closest point is of a different zone, set its field value to 1. This is not ideal because the zones border each other, and along the border you might have nearest neighbors be the other zone. However, it could thin your sample down enough to perform the manual task of identifying outliers.

Comment: I have a shp only points with a field of classification called "Zones" 
theoretically all points having ZO1 classification must be in the same area

Comment: So you don't have a polygon shapefile of the boundaries of each "zone"?

Comment: For some standard GIS functions to work - like spatial join - you would need the polygon layer to query against. I have added another answer to my previous answer, that might suffice.

Answer (score 3):

Since you only have points, one method you could try would be using the [Minimum Bounding Geometry (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003q000000) tool.  I tried using the "Convex Hull" option and grouped by an attribute field option.  If they are truly grouped in distinct areas (like for example, US States), you will see "spikes" that run across the screen for outliers.

Another similar, but slightly different approach would be to [Create Thiessen Polygons (Analysis)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001m000000) and then symbolize (color code) the polygons by Zone using a [Unique values renderer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s50000003m000000), like you have done with points.

Comment: You can specifically look for overlaps in the minimum bounding geometries from different groups: any incorrectly-zoned points should fall within an overlap (although an overlap won't necessarily indicate that there is an incorrectly-zoned point within it).